# ndb not querying by date correctly

Tags: python, google-app-engine, datetime, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I'm unit testing a method on the Expense model. The relevant parts of the model look like this:

```
class Expense(ndb.Model):

    user = ndb.KeyProperty(User, required=True)
    timestamp = ndb.DateTimeProperty(required=True)
    ...

    @staticmethod
    def new(user, amount, comment, description, timestamp):
        """creates a new expense and stores it. It returns the Expense instance"""
        ... validation ...
        exp = Expense(user=user, timestamp=timestamp, ...)
        exp.put()
        return exp

    @staticmethod
    def list(user, from_date=None, to_date=None):
        ...  
        query = Expense.query(Expense.user == user)
        if from_date is not None:
            if not isinstance(from_date, datetime.datetime):
                raise ValueError("from_date must be a datetime.datetime instance")
            query.filter(Expense.timestamp >= from_date)
        if to_date is not None:
            if not isinstance(to_date, datetime.datetime):
                raise ValueError("to_date must be a datetime.datetime instance")
            query.filter(Expense.timestamp <= to_date)
        query.order(- Expense.timestamp)
        return query
```

I have the following unit test to test `Expense.list`:

The first 4 lines of the test create instances of the Expense model instance.

- one on january 3rd 2013
- one on november 1st 2013
- one on november 2nd 2013
- one on january 1st 2014

home that saves you some horizontal scrolling.

```
def test_list_expenses_filter_by_date(user):
    expense1 = Expense.new(user=user, amount=200.12, description="a netbook", comment="", timestamp=datetime.datetime(year=2013, month=1, day=3, hour=12, minute=30))
    expense2 = Expense.new(user=user, amount=1.0, description="A can of coke", comment="Really cheap!",timestamp=datetime.datetime(year=2013, month=11, day=1, hour=12, minute=30))
    expense3 = Expense.new(user=user, amount=3.05, description="A burger", comment="Tasty!", timestamp=datetime.datetime(year=2013, month=11, day=2, hour=12))
    expense4 = Expense.new(user=user, amount=0.30, description="Toilet visit", comment="I normally don't pay for these things, but it was urgent.", timestamp=datetime.datetime(year=2014, month=1, day=1, hour=1, minute=15))

    from_date = datetime.datetime(year=2013, month=5, day=1)
    to_date = datetime.datetime(year=2013, month=12, day=31)
    exps  = Expense.list(user=user, from_date=from_date, to_date=to_date)
    for expense in exps:
        assert from_date <= expense.timestamp <= to_date
```

But when I run this test from pytest, I get an AssertionError on the following line, as displayed by pytest:

```
assert datetime.datetime(2013, 5, 1, 0, 0) <= datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 3, 12, 30)
```

E            +  where datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 3, 12, 30) = Expense(key=Key('Expense', 5066549580791808), amount=200.12, comment=u'', desc...tamp=datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 3, 12, 30), user=Key('User', 5629499534213120)).timestamp

So why is my `Expense.list` method returning instances with a dat that is out of range?

I've tried this both in the app engine testbed, and in a requesthandler, viewing the output in a browser, so it's not a bug in the datastore stub.

I've also tried building the query differently. Instead of calling `Query.filter` repeatedly, I added filter expressions to a list, passed that list as `*args` to `ndb.AND` and passed that to a single `Query.filter` but that didn't work either.

I've ruled out the possibility of a bug in ndb. The following test passes:

```
def test_ndb_date():
    from google.appengine.ext import ndb

    class Time(ndb.Model):
        timestamp = ndb.DateTimeProperty(required=True)

    t1 = Time(timestamp=datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=365))
    t2 = Time(timestamp=datetime.datetime.now())
    t3 = Time(timestamp=datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(days=365))
    ndb.put_multi([t1, t2, t3])
    from_date = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    to_date = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(days = 1)
    result = Time.query(Time.timestamp <= from_date, Time.timestamp >= to_date).fetch()
    for time in result:
        assert from_date <= time.timestamp >= to_date
```

Comment: try `return query.fetch()`

Comment: I've tried that. It gives me the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I misunderstood how `Query.filter` works. It doesn't alter the current `Query` instance, but returns a new one.

Comment: So, is it closed question? :)